# Enthought Canopy and Micro-Magager

Tags: python, wrapper, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to use the Micro-Manager wrapper for python
(https://micro-manager.org/wiki/Using_the_Micro-Manager_python_library)
with Canopy.
When I run the simplest demo program:

```
from MMCorePy import *
mmc = MMCorePy.CMMCore()

#  Load and initialize the demo camera device:
mmc.loadDevice("cam","DemoCamera","DCam")
mmc.initializeDevice("cam")

# Snap and retrieve an image:
mmc.snapImage()
im1 = mmc.getImage()

# Display the image:
from pylab import *
ion() # Activate interactive mode
figure()
imshow(im1,cmap = cm.gray)
```

I get and error that i can't repair:

```
ImportError: dlopen(./_MMCorePy.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZTI8CMMError
Referenced from: /Applications/Micro-Manager1.4/_MMCorePy.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /Applications/Micro-Manager1.4/_MMCorePy.so
```

I've tried to change the working directory to the folder where all the files are, as well as I tried to copy all the needed files in a new folder and use that one as a working directory. All the times, the same error. I just can't make it work!
p.s. 
The program I posted is just the demo given by Micro-Manager itself.
Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: install new stable Micro-Manager version, because yours wasn't built properly.

Near 25th Jan 2014 I was trying to build MM for Archlinux and had same issue as you with incomplete `setup.py` build script. There is missing *zlib*, *boost* and unlinked binaries. [This diff](https://github.com/radioxoma/aur/blob/d98b48ae7dbadb19e212e3b234cc4f56abbeaa59/micromanager-git/python_setup.diff) fixes issue.

[At now I see](https://github.com/mdcurtis/micromanager-upstream/commit/13250d0d9c99319e202a80a859bb46f2f3c427fa), MM devs totally switched from native python build system to Make. Seems to be, 1.4.17 version and newer was built without issue.